# Get Geopoints of <insert storechain> stores?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, plot, android-mapview

Is there a way to get all the geopoints of a storechain's stores?
If you f.e search for Ikea, walmart etc I would like to gather all the geopoints from the locations that google map or any other tool plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to look into the [google api license for geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) . basically you would be doing a name search to get an address and then geocoding to get the gps, but the google api has some limitations on how you can use the service like how many requests per day (2500) and you must show that data on a google map, etc